# using indicator in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, indicator

I am trying to use indicator in a report on a matrix. There is a column in my matrix called %Change and  want my indicator to reflect the data from that column. The data in that column is like in the following picture:

[image]

My indicator expression is the same as one in the %change data rows:

```
=iif(Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value) - 1, Fields!Fact_Person_Count.Value, 0)) = 0, 0, ((Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value), Fields!Fact_Person_Count.Value, 0)) / Sum(iif(Fields!Year.Value = Max(Fields!Year.Value) - 1, Fields!Fact_Person_Count.Value, 0))) - 1))
```

The indicator properties window looks like this:

[image]

The values in the start and end are the percentage value that the expression will output, and if the percent is between -1000% and -15% then it should be red downwards arrow if between -15% to 15% then it must be right yellow arrow and if more the 15% then green upwards arrow.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because the output literally shows indicators at random data rows (see the following images):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update:

After the changes I made:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are a total of 7 outputs in the report, devided through different years. thats why 7 images. Whats funny is the 4th column throughout doesnt show any values

Comment: I know you are confident that the expression is the same, but are you able to add a text box to the same cell as the indicator is in and output the percentage values directly to the screen.

Comment: well i added a test box and just previewed, it gave an integer output, but i changed the properties of text box to percentage and then added the indicator with the same properties, and now its not showing any indicator value

Comment: What was the integer value?  Have you tried using the indicator based on these integer values rather then the percentages?

Comment: yes i did, i kept everything same and just added in a column on left called indicator values and i copy pasted the expression from indicator to the row data to see the real values. see my question update in 3 mins, i ll put the output report images there

Comment: just to clarify i changed the values in the indicator properties by *100

Answer (score 0):

If your textbox expression and the indicator expression are the same then Try to change the state Measurement Unit proporty into Numeric

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecGnP.png)